# AWS CDK TypeScript issue [type='CNAME'] but it already exists

Tags: typescript, amazon-route53, typescript-generics, aws-cdk, cname

I am new to AWS CDK TypeScript.

My issue is: `[Tried to create resource record set [name='xxxxx', type='CNAME'] but it already exists]"}`

Using AWS CDK TypeScript I am creating stacks in eu-west1 and eu-central regions. So is there any mechanism to check if cname is not created then only create?

My code current code:

```
   const cName = new route53.CnameRecord(this, "cName", {
            zone: route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, "lowerHostedZone3", {
                domainName: topDomain,
            }),
  
            recordName: topFQDN,
            domainName: lowerFQDN

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying the stack in multiple regions will probably create the same entry twice (one for `eu-west-1` and one for `eu-central-1`). Since `route53` is a global service, this could be the cause of the error you see.

Instead of doing a lookup you can simply choose to make 1 region leading for DNS, or include the region name in the DNS entries (`my-service.eu-west-1.my-domain.com`), and then front it with something like cloudfront or global accelerator to do global routing to the nearest region.

Comment: sorry but I want to implement a mechanism that will check if the cname exists, if not then only create else skip so is it feasible in aws CDK typescript?

Comment: Well it's not easy, since you'd probably only have to have that data available during synthesis time (if you don't want to use custom resources). This means that you have to do some lookups using the AWS SDK, check if a record exists, and if not add the construct to your stack. However this is not a guarantee that during deployment time you don't run into conflicts (during synth no records might be present, but deploy 2 stacks with the same record and you still run into the conflict). So your best bet would be a custom resource, which is probably way too much work for the value it delivers.

Comment: That's against CDK best practices. Your synths should be deterministic, i.e. not depend on the environment they're run in.

Comment: oh then is it possible that at least my deployment doesn't fail if the resource is already present?

Comment: or Something like if failed creating cname skip/continue next line.

Comment: No that's not possible. You should basically be aware whether or not the record is present already before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and would like to avoid others spending 24 hours working on it. My answer is for the generic problem: "name" already exists.

Get rid of them. Get rid of all instances of names that are optional to the classes being invoked. Let them generate it for you. Don't use try blocks, don't try to retrieve them if it exists (at the time of writing, such an approach did not work).

Don't delete the stack every time to solve this issue, simply do not use names.

[Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/resources.html)